# usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCbc

Tags: ubuntu, make, configure

I'm trying to use make, it returns these errors and simmilar ones :

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCbc
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgl
```

I have already found similar issues, and tried a great deal of them. None was useful.
for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary

Details:
I am using ubuntu 16.04

I have installed some libraries like Vol and Cgl from coin-or:https://projects.coin-or.org/ 
libraries, executables and header files are installed in directories like "/home/MyPc/Descktop/CoinOrPaks/Vol-1.5.3/lib", 
"/home/MyPc/Descktop/CoinOrPaks/Vol-1.5.3/bin", "/home/MyPc/Descktop/CoinOrPaks/Vol-1.5.3/include" respectively. 
My codes are stored in "home/MyPc/Descktop/NsProj/Sourcee"

Then I use

```
env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/MyPc/Descktop/CoinOrPaks/Vol-1.5.3/lib/pkgconfig:
home/MyPc/Descktop/CoinOrPaks/Cgl-0.59.10/build/lib/pkgconfig cmake home/MyPc/Descktop/NsProj/Sourcee
```

and give address of pkgconfig for non standard directories
The above command executes OK. and says found messeges like: Found Cgl version 0.59.10

However after that when I use `make`...

and get those errors

Comment: Randomly applying "similar" solutions without understanding the problem is not going to help. You need to (1) find out in which directory the `libCbc.*` and `libCgl.*` are on your system (which you told us nothing about), and then (2) add the correct path to your `cmake` configuration (which you also told us nothing about, possibly it's not even calling `pkgconfig`).

Comment: Please check (via `ls`) if the libraries in `/home/MyPc/Descktop/CoinOrPaks/Vol-1.5.3/lib` are static (`.a`) or (dynamic `.so`). For the latter, check if symlinks are present. You'll also need to read up on `ldconfig` to execute the resulting binary (once it comples). Invoke `pkg-config` manually, and check if it gives the correct library path for your two libraries ("found Cgl ..." may still point to some other package, you need to check the *path*, i.e. `pkg-config -libs ...`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the libraries `libCbc`, and `libCgl`, installed. You will need the `dev` versions of these libraries. e.g. `libCbc-dev`

```
apt install coinor-libCgl-dev coinor-libCbc-dev
```

Comment: I think they are installed correctly, as instructed in https://projects.coin-or.org/Vol

Comment: When you did `./configure`, did you tell it where to find the libraries?

Comment: You need to tell it where your libraries are, else it will not find them. Do `./configure --help`